# how to change eclipse default dialog box to debug configuration dialog

Tags: eclipse, configuration, preference

When eclipse is started it should directly open debug configuration dialog box.

[debug configuration dialog image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIfq5.png)

how to achieve the same?
do I have to change any preferences to achieve the same ?

Comment: There is no support for opening this (or any other) dialog at start up.

Comment: is there any shortcut to go directly to debug configuration dialog after startup ?

Comment: Is Ctrl+click on the debug icon in the main toolbar what you are looking for?

Comment: debug icon in the main toolbar is not visible after the eclipse starts in my case